# How to make an airflow dag skip an hour if previous trigger is still in motion

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

A simple question for airflow DAG development

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': dates.days_ago(1),
    'email': ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_success': True,
    'schedule_interval': '0 * * * *',
}
```

The above configuration states that the DAG should run every hour on the top of the hour.

How do I make the job skip one hour if the previous job is still in motion?

Thanks!

Comment: On the DAG level, this behaviour is not configurable. You may have to have another DAG perform the task of watching over dag runs and enacting this decision.

Comment: What behaviour do you want the scheduler to do? You can set `max_active_runs=1` in `args`, Airflow will schedule your DAGs every hour, but they will remain `queued` until the previous DAG has finished has completed. Airflow will run a DAG for each hour, and delay the execution. Or does your dag not rely on the schedule being exactly 1 hour, and you're fine letting a DAG run for 2 hours, and just run again on the next hour after its finished?

Comment: Hi Daniel.  The code below the DAG calls an API, and I have a liimit on the API to a certain number of calls per hour.  so I want to just run again on the next available hour after finished.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment you can achieve what you want by setting `max_active_runs=1`. However, this will depend on wider context of expected behaviour.

If you need more complex schedule consider implementing your own [Timetable](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.0/howto/timetable.html).